# Storm Crawler- Crawling the websites which require authentication

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I would like to crawl websites which require authorization (I already have credentials) in intranet with Storm Crawler. Is it possible to do that by simply modifying the crawler configuration or should I alter the classes in the source code, if so, which classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not currently available. I have opened an issue for this [#427](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/427), you'd need to modify the HttpProtocol class. This would be a great contribution and would be very welcome.